# How to hook mouse on Linux (X11 lib) with JNA?

Tags: linux, mouse, hook, x11, jna

I don't know library to hook.
Please converse this code to jna code.
[How can I get the current mouse (pointer) position co-ordinates in X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585871/how-can-i-get-the-current-mouse-pointer-position-co-ordinates-in-x)

Answer (score 1):

Java provides [a method to obtain mouse coordinates](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/MouseInfo.html#getPointerInfo%28%29).  If your JVM version does not support this method, then you need to open the X11 display, start an event loop, and listen for mouse motion events.

```
Display* dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
XEvent ev;
XMaskEvent(dpy, PointerMotionMask, &ev);
```

The platform.jar library included with JNA includes a number of X11 library mappings and constants which should help.