# Look up specific button (ButtonPress Events in Xlib)

Tags: gcc, xlib

I'm looking for a similar function as `XLookupKeysym(XKeyEvent*,int)` for the `ButtonPress` events, so i can check what button was pressed. With `XGrabButton(...)` i'm getting notifications on every `ButtonPress` event.

How do I check for a specific button (e.g `XK_Pointer_Button1`) if it's pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found what I wanted:

```
...
switch(&Event.type):
   case ButtonPress:
      if(Event.xbutton.button == Button1)
         ...
```

Seems to be that I've mistaken `XK_Pointer_Button1` with that `Button1` I used above. It's defined in X.h, not in keysymdef.h.

If found the answer here:
[getting mouseclick coordinates with Xlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122196/getting-mouseclick-coordinates-with-xlib)

Answer (score 0):

[XQueryPointer](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XQueryPointer.html) gives you mouse buttons state in addition to pointer coordinates

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But I made a mistake. See my answer.