# Errors while trying to get mouse click coordinates

Tags: c, linux, mouseevent, xlib

I'm trying to run the code from this topic (first answer): [getting mouseclick coordinates with Xlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122196/getting-mouseclick-coordinates-with-xlib?newreg=316884dca6c34c11804c42c4ba8afb00) and it gives me some errors.

Output:

```
$ ./a.out
X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
  Major opcode of failed request:  2 (X_ChangeWindowAttributes)
  Serial number of failed request:  8
  Current serial number in output stream:  8
```

Comment: Try with: `gcc -lX11 c.cc`

Comment: You wanna say : gcc c.cc -lX11, @nnn there is another problem (updated)

Comment: Yeah, the lib have to be added after the source files. But initially you had a link problem, you should have updated the question specifying that it got solved and now you have another issue. Anyway, have you read the comments from that answer? It should work by changing to `XSelectInput(display, root, ButtonReleaseMask);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should use: `gcc c.cc -lX11`
And change one string to: `XSelectInput(display, root, ButtonReleaseMask);`